# Adding the powers of numbers in haskell with foldl

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am being asked to make an haskell function that computes something like

```
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ...
```

While I find it quite easy to implement with list comprehensions

```
sum [ k^2 | k <- [1..100]]
```

or maps

```
sum (map (\x -> x*x) [1..100])
```

I'm having some hard time getting how to achieve it with foldls.

If I am not wrong, one needs no less than 3 parameters in a recursive function to achieve a result with this:

1. The current position (1... up to n)
2. The current sum
3. Where to stop

Even if I define this function, it will still return a tuple, not a number (like I need it to!).

Could anyone be kind enough to give me some clues on what I may be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "current position" (actually the next item in the list, just like in your map and list comprehension versions) and where to stop are implicit in the list being folded over.  The current sum is the "accumulator" parameter of the fold.  So, fill in the blank:

```
foldl (\runningSum nextNumber -> ____) 0 [1..100]
```

Comment: Incidentally, I would also generally recommend `foldl'` (defined in Data.List) for this, which forces the accumulator to be evaluated at every step.  When compiling with GHC it figures that out anyway, but in GHCi or Hugs it can make the difference between running in constant space or running out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the definition of `sum`, it's just `sum = foldl (+) 0`. So if you replace `sum` with `foldl (+) 0` in either of your solutions, you have a solution using `foldl`.

You can also get rid of the need for list comprehensions or `map` by using `foldl` with a function that adds the square of its second argument to its first argument.

I'm not sure where your considerations about recursive functions figure into this. If you're using `foldl`, you don't need to use recursion (except in so far that `foldl` is implemented using recursion).

However, you are wrong that a recursive function would need three arguments: A recursive functions summing the squares of each element in a list, would most straight-forwardly implemented by taking a list and adding the head of the list to the result of calling the function on the list's tail. The base case being `squareSum [] = 0`. This has nothing to with `foldl`, though.

Comment: Although the idea is nice, that sounds a bit like cheating. I don't believe that's what the teacher is asking for :(

Comment: @devoured: I don't know what else he'd possibly be asking for (you should probably get rid of `map` and the list comprehensions as explained in my second paragraph). If the assignment says to use `foldl`, you're most certainly not supposed to use explicit recursion.